Como generar report de cucumber con el perfil POM - Maven
Estoy intentando lanzar pruebas con cucumber ejecutando con un perfil de maven. Toda la ejecución es un exito, lo unio que estoy teniendo problemas es a la hora de reproducir el report de cucumber. Os paso el codigo del perfil para que lo veais mejor: al ejecutar con Maven y la herramienta con Intellij es clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@quick
<!-- quick -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>cucumber-quick</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <driver.class>org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver</driver.class>
                            <driver.file>bin/chromedriver</driver.file>
                            <driver.name>browsers.ChromeBrowserConfiguration</driver.name>
                            <driver.type>webdriver.chrome.driver</driver.type>
                            <cucumber.options>--tags ${cucumber.quick.tag}</cucumber.options>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>5.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>prueba</projectName>
                                <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                                <!-- this value will specify the json report path -->
                                <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                                <jsonFiles>
                                    <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                    <param>*.json</param>
                                </jsonFiles>
                                <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true"
                                 to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                               <!-- <skip>${skipCucumberReporting}</skip>-->
                                <skip>${skipCucumberReporting}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

El testng.xml está creado con paralelo pero eso es indiferente porque ahora mismo estoy ejecutando con un hilo y solo una prueba:
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "summary",
        "html:target/test-report-1.html",
        "json:target/test-report-1.json",
        "junit:target/test-report-1.xml",
        "timeline:target/cucumber-timeline",
},
        snippets = CAMELCASE,
        glue = "feature",
        features = "src/test/features/01 - Login")
public class RunMainTest1 extends RunMainTest{
} 

Si creo un metodo en java si me lo hace, parece que algo no me está haciendo caso en mi perfil

Es el perfil de ejecución del Maven, paso el código por si algun@ tiene el mismo problema: clean test verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@quick -DgenerateReport=true
Debemos poner verify para el reporte, el cucumber.filter.tags para indicar que tags queremos lanzar.
